# Method for evaluating the unit vector ( or normalising a vector ) in Python or in the numerical libraries: numpy, scipy

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, scipy

Is there a built-in method for normalising an n-vector ( i.e. evaluating the unit vector **v**_{hat} =  **v**/||**v**|| for an n-dimensional vector) in Python or in either of the major Python numerical libraries numpy or scipy?

I've written a method using norm from the numpy linear algebra module (numpy.linalg):

```
def normaliseVector(nVector):
    return nVector/numpy.linalg.norm(nVector)
```

which seems to work fine. I tested it with the following input:

```
normaliseVector([3, 4, 5])
```

which returns the correct answer for this case. It just struck me that there might be a method out there for doing this already, or if not that it might be a useful thing to have a well-tested method for this.

Comment: As the marked duplicate specifically deals with scikit-learn: Yes, dividing by `np.linalg.norm` is the canonical way to do this in numpy.  There's no built in function for it.  However, if you'd prefer to do the operation in-place (faster, saves memory, but modifies the input), you can do `vector /= np.linalg.norm(vector)`.  Don't use `/=` unless you are aware of datatype issues (it will produce an array of zeros with any integer datatype) and in-place modification, though!